# Checking Character in a String using .equals() not working

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to check if a letter submitted by user is contained in a string, but it always return false. From what I read the .equals() function should work. I was expecting that if a user inputs the letter "a" it would return "pass" if the string was "america".

```
 for (int i = 0; i < outputTest.length(); i++){
                    if (userInput.equals(outputTest.charAt(i))){
                        System.out.println("Pass");
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("Fail");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Comment: Send me your outputTest variable.. i mean what is it contains ?

Comment: Use `outputTest.substring(i, i + 1)` instead of `outputTest.charAt(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `outputTest.length()` and `outputTest.charAt()` I am assuming that `outputTest` is String.
Based on `userInput.equals` I am assuming it is not primitive type like `char` (since primitive types don't have methods). It is also not `Character`, otherwise you would see `Pass` few times. So it most likely is also String.

---

`outputTest.charAt(i)` returns `char`, but you are comparing it with `String` which equals method looks like:

```
964  public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
965      if (this == anObject) {
966          return true;
967      }
968      if (anObject instanceof String) {
969          String anotherString = (String)anObject;
970          int n = value.length;
971          if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
972              char v1[] = value;
973              char v2[] = anotherString.value;
974              int i = 0;
975              while (n-- != 0) {
976                  if (v1[i] != v2[i])
977                      return false;
978                  i++;
979              }
980              return true;
981          }
982      }
983      return false;
984  }
```

So since `equals` expects `Object`, `char` (returned from `outputTest.charAt(i)`) will be automatically boxed to `Character`, but since `Character` doesn't extend `String` test

```
if (anObject instanceof String)
```

will fail and you will immediately move to `return false;`.

---

You may want to use `contains` method if you want to check if one `String` contains another

```
outputTest.contains(userInput)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find a string in another string, just do:

```
return text.contains(string);
```

To find a char in a string, do

```
return text.indexOf(ch) > -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of your object **userInput**? You seem to be comparing a String object with a character which is returned by the charAt() method. That will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

When you are learning to use methods, a good habit to develop is to look at what kind of data type the methods apply or return. For instance, you cannot code this: `char scanner.nextLine() // nextLine() is to read String, not char.` Therefore, in your code `outputTest.charAt(i) // I am a char`, and this `userInput.equals() // I am a String`, you are comparing different things. You cannot compare an apple with a desk because they are two different objects. The compiler will always tell you false.

I assume: `String inputTest = scanner.nextLine();` for user input a letter, and you can consider `"a"` as a String with a length 1. (or any other letters inside)

```
    if (outputTest.contains(userInput)) // now you are comparing String and String
       System.out.println("Pass");
    else
       System.out.println("Fail");
```